# Problem with specific wifi connection

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, network-manager

I am having a problem with connecting to a wifi in ubuntu 18.04. I have two wifi one is working fine but another one is not connecting. When I open the browser it says - "Activation of network connection has failed". Wired connection is also not working for that particular network. I tried the Mobile hotspot, which is also working. Please help me.

Comment: WPA/WPA2 Personal

Comment: Possibly related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839

Comment: I installed ubuntu in other free space of HDD. this time I didn't installed third-party software for graphics and wifi drivers and now I am able to connect to that wifi. Any idea why this was happening?